# Java Buffer which can tell if it's dirty

Tags: java, byte, arrays, bytebuffer

Due to the existing structure of code, which looks like this:

```
// Read buffer (using ByteBuffer)
// Pass buffer to a remote method, which MIGHT write to it
// Write buffer back if dirty
```

I want that my buffer should be able to identify if it is written to (if it's dirty). I didn't find any buffer implementation in java with a dirty flag.

In all these cases my code is already passing around `ByteBuffers`, in order to add this dirty flag should I:

- simply wrap the `ByteBuffer` implementation with dirty flag
- Write a class with underlying `byte` array, add dirty big and other operations 
  (get/put int or long) and re-create the `ByteBuffer` by wrapping around 
  the `byte` array
- Extend the `ByteBuffer` class? (I'd be happy to implement the get/put but there
  are WAY TOO many methods to be implemented)

Also, what are the overheads of wrapping the `ByteBuffer` implementation?

Comment: Why do you need to know if it is dirty. Perhaps there is another way such as using memory mapped files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem where the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) applies.  You are strictly adding simple functionality to an existing class that's already in use.  In this case, extending the class by inheritance is a natural and low threat implementation.

The overhead in Java of using the extended class vs. the base class is essentially zero. I am not counting as "overhead" the space for the dirty flag and the few instructions needed to implement it.  But these costs are very low as well.

Comment: I was just going to write the exact same thing you did, so +1 for beating me to it :)